# Broken Laptop Screen can't see bios or windows installation

Tags: windows, laptop, display, multiple-monitors, bios

I have an dell 3500 g3 and the screen is broken and something else related to the screen doesnt work so fixing it is really expensive, almost same price as the laptop so I won'to do that.It works perfectly well with a HDMI Monitor but the problem is The first thing I can see on the monitor is Windows Starting before that everything is black.So when I try to Install windows or go in BIOS all I see is black on the external monitor.Probably the bios and windows installation shows on the laptop screen but it doesnt work so that doesn't help me.I searched everwhere I tried a lot of stuff and I didn't find any solution to this.

Comment: You cannot get into BIOS or any like output on an external screen on a laptop - certainly most laptops and any I have seen

Comment: So I guess there is nothing I can do. Unlucky I just wanted to reinstall my windows

Comment: Dont trust me - I dont specialize in Laptop repair, but if my Google Foo is correct you can get a new internal screen for US $120 or so (see https://www.ebay.com/itm/353707002171)  or even much less - https://www.laptopscreen.com/English/model/Dell/G3~15~3500/  - so maybe try the repair yourself or  get a quote from an independant repair co?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately with Laptops (> 95%) you need the screen for BIOS and like outputs.

So, you either have to repair the laptop or replace the machine.

That is what we all have to do.